# How to migrate from build flow plugin to pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have a build flow similar to below code

```
parallel (
    {
        build("job1A")
        build("job1B")
        build("job1C")
    },
    {
        build("job2A")
        build("job2B")
        build("job2C")
    }
)
```

How can I make the same flow run in a pipeline job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really simple, you can use the parallel step:

```
def jobs = [
    "part1": {
        build("job1A")
        build("job1B")
        build("job1C")
    },
    "part2": {
        build("job2A")
        build("job2B")
        build("job2C")
    }
]

parallel jobs
```

If you don't know how to write the pipeline script refer to the [Snippet Generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#writing-pipeline-scripts-in-the-jenkins-ui).

**Parameterized job calls:**

```
build job: 'job1A', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Test', value: 'testvalue']]
```

More details about the classes can be found in the [reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job).

Comment: Not sure if `node()` is needed here: an external job selects its slave according to its configuration so that wrapping `node()` can't affect it.